# Joomla plugin unique alias

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I need to auto-generate different aliases from two articles with the same title in Joomla 3.3. The user will add articles in the front end. I found this code:

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgContentRandom_Alias extends JPlugin
{

  function onContentBeforeSave($context, &$article, $isNew) {


  if(!$isNew){
    return;
  }

  $alias = $article->alias;
  $n = substr( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ,mt_rand( 0 ,25 ) ,1 ) .substr( md5( time( ) ) ,1 );


  $table = JTable::getInstance('content');
  while ($table->load(array('alias' => $alias))) {
    $new_alias = $alias . $n;
  }
  $article->alias = $new_alias;   
  return true;
  }

}
?>
```

, and made a plugin for Joomla, but the plugin not working in Joomla 3.3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own plugin using the following code, although this functionality should be already part of joomla core.
I've used this because of Seblod error when using its insert content form.

## Files:

Joomla installer descriptor: 
**uniqueAliasGenerator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
    <name>Content - Unique alias generator</name>
    <author>McGiogen</author>
    <creationDate>May 2015</creationDate>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <license></license>
    <authorEmail>mcgiogen@hotmail.it</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.joomla.org</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>
        Automatic generator of unique alias.
        At save time it append "-X" (where X is a numeric identifier)
        if article alias is already in database.
    </description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="uniqueAliasGenerator">uniqueAliasGenerator.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Plugin code:
**uniqueAliasGenerator.php**

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class plgContentUniqueAliasGenerator extends JPlugin
{   
    /**
     * Alias check and generation before save content method.
     * Content is passed by reference. Method is called before the content is saved.
     *
     * @param   string  $context  The context of the content passed to the plugin (added in 1.6).
     * @param   object  $article  A JTableContent object.
     * @param   bool    $isNew    If the content is just about to be created.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function onContentBeforeSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
        if ($context == 'com_content.article' && $article->alias && $isNew) {
            $oldAlias = $article->alias;
            $categoryId = $article->catid;  //An alias must be unique only in its category
            $article->alias = $this->getUniqueAlias($oldAlias, $categoryId);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Find unique Alias name if current doesn't exist.
     * @param string $alias Alias of the article
     * @param string $catId Id of article's category
     * 
     * @return string Return the unique alias value.
     */
    protected function getUniqueAlias($alias, $catId)
    {
        $alias_ini = $alias;

        for ($i = 2; $this->isAliasExist($alias, $catId); $i++) {
            $alias = $alias_ini . '-' . $i;   
        }
        return $alias;
    }

    /**
     * Check the 'alias' in the database.
     *
     * @return boolean If found return true else false.
     */
    protected function isAliasExist($alias, $catId) 
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query
            ->select('COUNT(*)')
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))    //Articles table
            ->where($db->quoteName('alias') . ' = ' . $db->quote($alias))
            ->where($db->quoteName('catid') . ' = ' . $db->quote($catId));  //Category ID
        $db->setQuery($query);

        return ($db->loadResult() ? true : false);
    }
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>
```

## How to use:

Create files with the same names, put them in a folder called "uniqueAliasGenerator", zip in "uniqueAliasGenerator.zip", upload and install on your joomla.

Compatible with Joomla 3.x, tested on Joomla 3.4.1

#### Update 11 Nov 2017

Added check of $isNew. Thanks @robert-drygas.

Answer (score 0):

In McGiogen code the line

```
if ($context == 'com_content.article' && $article->alias) {
```

can be write as

```
if ($context == 'com_content.article' && $article->alias && $isNew) {
```

so unique alias will be ganerated only for the new articles (without altered existing aliases when editing old articles).